# is it possible to have reports about downloads by dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, sharing, file-sharing

i upload my learning packages on Dropbox. and put their links on my shop ...

10 people simultaneously download files easy and with no problem

i want to have automatic reports send me as attachment to me by email every month. or every scheduled time.

i want to have reports about downloads that brokes

i want to have histogram about statistics.

is it possible to send links for my customer by filling request form and then email (for example links generated randomly and works one time only. for one day.)

is there these features in Dropbox?

is there any other service for this goal?

please edit my question if ask some question that not related. please help me to decide and choose best.

Comment: Can you clarify about the reports a bit? Do you want to know about the frequency/access to downloads or do you just want to know about any errors? Are you currently having problems with links breaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think this is possibly in Dropbox although it is on the wishlist for Dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/14/analytics-statistics-for-public-files)

So yes you would need another service for this goal.

There are thousands of different possibilities. Just a cheap one: install WordPress and install one of the "download" plugins: that will give you statistics on how many people downloaded a certain item (e.g. http://wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/)

Comment: Dropbox's vote box has been shut down.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way out there is to use our app for Dropbox.  Tracks the number of times a dropbox file was downloaded using a share link.

http://orangedox.com/dropbox

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service providing such analytic.

For example, I use [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) to shorten the links. Bit.ly also provides "Stats" page that counts the number of views/downloads against time and geographic location.